# Drop a immutable borrow to make a mutable borrow

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am still learning Rust and when trying to implement Dikjstra as part of a training project, I encountered this peculiar catch. First I define a `HashMap`:

```
let mut dist: HashMap<Node, usize> = HashMap::new();
```

And later:

```
let state = State { node: next_node.clone(), cost: cost + 1 };
let current_dist = dist.get(&state.node);
if (current_dist == None) || (state.cost < *current_dist.unwrap()) {
    dist.insert(state.node.clone(), state.cost);
    heap.push(state);
}
```

Which yields a compile error because `dist.get` triggers a immutable borrow which stays in scope until after the `if ... {...}` statement, and in particular when I `dist.insert`, asking for a mutable borrow.

I think I miss a pattern or a keyword allowing me this type of process. For now I tried a `drop` at the beginning of the `if` scope, and other `current_dist` evaluation such as

```
let current_dist;
{
    current_dist = dist.get(&state.node);
}
```

or

```
let current_dist = {|| dist.get(&state.node)}();
```

but the end of scope of the immutable borrow still happen after the `if` statement.

Comment: `(current_dist == None) | (state.cost < *current_dist.unwrap())` I can't imagine that you want a bitwise OR operation there.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. You haven't defined what `Node`, `State` or `heap` are.

Comment: I corrected the `||`. The definition of `State` seemed implied by the creation of `state`, and `Node` and `heap` didn't seem relevant (`Node` is a set of coordinates, `heap` is a heap).

Comment: *and `Node` and `heap` didn't seem relevant* — then **remove them from your question**. Again, I strongly encourage you to review what we mean by a [MCVE]; emphasis on the **Minimal**. The reason for doing this is twofold: 1. by reducing the problem, you are more likely to solve it yourself, 2. a reduced problem is easier for *other* people to quickly understand. These people include answerers *and* future question askers who find your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## After non-lexical lifetimes

Since [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) are now enabled, the original code compiles. That being said, you should still use the [*entry API*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) for efficiency, otherwise you have to hash the key multiple times:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut dist: HashMap<u8, u8> = HashMap::new();

    let cost = 21;

    match dist.entry(42) {
        Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
            entry.insert(42);
        }
        Entry::Occupied(mut entry) => {
            if *entry.get() < cost {
                entry.insert(42);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Before non-lexical lifetimes

> because `dist.get` triggers a mutable borrow

No, [it's just an immutable borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get):

```
pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

> I tried a `drop`

[Explicit drops do not affect lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35765440/155423).

> ```
> let current_dist;
> {
>     current_dist = dist.get(&state.node);
> }
> ```

Here you aren't fooling anyone. If the compiler was confused by this, it wouldn't be very good. This **still** has a borrow to the `HashMap`, there's just some extra blocks scattered about.

> ```
> let current_dist = {|| dist.get(&state.node)}();
> ```

Same here. Returning the reference from a closure is *still returning a reference*. You really cannot easily trick the compiler into thinking that your reference to the `HashMap` doesn't exist.

---

You need to use a block to constrain how long the borrow exists. the simplest transformation is something akin to:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut dist: HashMap<u8, u8> = HashMap::new();

    let do_it = {
        let current_dist = dist.get(&42);
        current_dist == None || true
    };

    if do_it {
        dist.insert(42, 42);
    }
}
```

This isn't the prettiest, but some combinators can clean it up:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut dist: HashMap<u8, u8> = HashMap::new();

    let cost = 21;

    if dist.get(&42).map_or(true, |&val| val < cost) {
        dist.insert(42, 42);
    }
}
```

Note that now there's no more implicit panic from the `unwrap` call.

See also:

- [How to update-or-insert on a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47395171/155423)

Comment: I corrected the (im)mutable, that was a typo. The pointers given are exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you! Came here wondering how the heck to call ".get()" on a HashMap and then ".remove()" on the same map based on the value of get() call without running into "cannot borrow X as mutable because it was also borrowed as immutable".