# How can I mutate a slice when I know that there are no more references to its current content?

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

On an embedded device without a heap, I want to parse input data and store the found results in an output slice. I have a reader which allows me to get the currently available data and a parser which matches the input data to the expected format and stores the results in a slice of `Parsed::Value`s which could possibly hold references to the input data.

Since the Rust compiler sees that there could be references to the input data, I can not mutate the data buffer more than once. Since I can ensure that there are no references anymore by manually resetting the output slice to `Parsed::Unused`, I think that it should be safe to reuse the buffer. How can I achieve to mutate the input buffer in every iteration of the loop?

The following is my minimal example which illustrates my problem:

```rust
trait Reader {
    fn peek<'a>(&self, data: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8]; // copy currently available bytes from ringbuffer
    fn consume(&self, num: usize);                      // drop at the head of input queue
}

trait Parser {
    fn parse<'a>(&self, input: &'a [u8], parsed_value: &mut [Parsed<'a>]) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

enum Parsed<'a> {
    Unused,
    Value(&'a [u8]),
}

fn read_and_parse<'a>(
    reader: impl Reader,
    parser: impl Parser,
    data_buffer: &'a mut [u8],
    values: &mut [Parsed<'a>],
) {
    loop {
        for v in values.iter_mut() {
                                 // This block should ensure that no more
            *v = Parsed::Unused; // references are held into the buffer
        }                        // used in the previous iteration.
        let rx = reader.peek(data_buffer);
        if let Ok(()) = parser.parse(rx, values) {
            return;
        }
        reader.consume(1); // this could be replaced with smarter logic how to drop input bytes
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f7e5677c2042818e605e915fc65a523c)

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*data_buffer` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:26:30
   |
15 | fn read_and_parse<'a>(
   |                   -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
26 |         let rx = reader.peek(data_buffer);
   |                  ------------^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                  |           |
   |                  |           mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
   |                  argument requires that `*data_buffer` is borrowed for `'a`
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is this safe? Logically splitting a borrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64902078/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [How to update-or-insert on a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47395171/155423); [Double mutable borrow error in a loop happens even with NLL on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50519147/155423); [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423); [When is it necessary to circumvent Rust's borrow checker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50440074/155423)

Comment: The problem stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519147/double-mutable-borrow-error-in-a-loop-happens-even-with-nll-on seems to be the closest to my problem. Unfortunately, the answer there reveals that this does not work with the current borrow checker anyways. 
Still, my problem is different because I was trying to reuse the `values` slice in the second iteration, just after making sure manually that no references to the previous buffer are kept. I found that this can not be compiled successfully, even when using Polonius.
So I have to find a different approach or use transmute?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One thing that seems to work in many cases is to [transmute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/fn.transmute.html) the slice which can also be used to change lifetimes. Since this is "incredibly unsafe" in general, I personally try to avoid this function and to find different approaches to my problem instead. In many cases, those have even turned out to be cleaner.

Nevertheless, the example here [compiles successfully (playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d1fa2714cb41628b5b14b263364abe2c) with `transmute`:

```rust
trait Reader {
    fn peek<'a>(&self, data: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8];
    fn consume(&self, num: usize);
}

trait Parser {
    fn parse<'a>(&self, input: &'a [u8], parsed_value: &mut [Parsed<'a>]) -> Result<(),()>;
}

enum Parsed<'a> {
    Unused,
    Value(&'a [u8])
}

fn read_and_parse<'a>(reader: impl Reader, parser: impl Parser, data_buffer: &'a mut [u8], values: &mut [Parsed<'a>]) {
    loop {
        for v in values.iter_mut() { // This block should ensure that no more
            *v = Parsed::Unused;     // references are held into the buffer
        }                            // used in the previous iteration.
        let data_buffer = unsafe { core::mem::transmute(&mut *data_buffer) };
        let rx = reader.peek(data_buffer);
        if let Ok(()) = parser.parse(rx, values) {
            return;
        }
        reader.consume(1);
    }
}
```