# What are the best practices for multiple mutable and immutable borrows?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm developing a function that returns the content of a particular file in a Zip archive. Since I know the location of the file, I try to access it with the `ZipArchive.by_name` method. However, it is possible that the name of the file is written in a different case. If this happens (`FileNotFound`), I need to iterate over all files in the archive and perform a case-insensitive comparison with the template. However, in this case I get two errors connected with the borrowing.

Here is the minimal example (I use BarcodeScanner Android app (`../test_data/simple_apks/BarcodeScanner4.0.apk`) but you can use any apk file, just substitute path to it. You can download one, e.g., on [ApkMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/)):

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fs::File, path::Path};

const MANIFEST_MF_PATH: &str = "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";

fn main() {
    let apk_path = Path::new("../test_data/simple_apks/BarcodeScanner4.0.apk");
    let _manifest_data = get_manifest_data(apk_path);
}

fn get_manifest_data(apk_path: &Path) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let f = File::open(apk_path)?;
    let mut apk_as_archive = zip::ZipArchive::new(f)?;

    let _manifest_entry = match apk_as_archive.by_name(MANIFEST_MF_PATH) {
        Ok(manifest) => manifest,
        Err(zip::result::ZipError::FileNotFound) => {
            let manifest_entry = apk_as_archive
                .file_names()
                .find(|f| f.eq_ignore_ascii_case(MANIFEST_MF_PATH));

            match manifest_entry {
                Some(entry) => apk_as_archive.by_name(entry).unwrap(),
                None => {
                    return Err(Box::new(zip::result::ZipError::FileNotFound));
                }
            }
        }
        Err(err) => {
            return Err(Box::new(err));
        }
    };

    Ok(String::new()) //stub
}
```

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "multiple_borrows"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Yury"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
zip = "^0.5.8"
```

Here are the errors:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `apk_as_archive` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:17:34
   |
14 |     let _manifest_entry = match apk_as_archive.by_name(MANIFEST_MF_PATH) {
   |                                 ----------------------------------------
   |                                 |
   |                                 mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                 a temporary with access to the mutable borrow is created here ...
...
17 |             let manifest_entry = apk_as_archive
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
31 |     };
   |      - ... and the mutable borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `std::result::Result<ZipFile<'_>, ZipError>`

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `apk_as_archive` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:22:32
   |
14 |     let _manifest_entry = match apk_as_archive.by_name(MANIFEST_MF_PATH) {
   |                                 ----------------------------------------
   |                                 |
   |                                 first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                 a temporary with access to the first borrow is created here ...
...
22 |                 Some(entry) => apk_as_archive.by_name(entry).unwrap(),
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
31 |     };
   |      - ... and the first borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `std::result::Result<ZipFile<'_>, ZipError>`
```

I understand that these errors are connected with poor architectural decisions. What are the best practices in this case?

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423); [Double mutable borrow error in a loop happens even with NLL on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50519147/155423); [Is it safe to logically split a borrow to work around a limitation of the NLL-enabled borrow-checker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64902078/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I've added minimal working example (it's not that different from the previous one). Also, I've added my `Cargo.toml` file with zip dependency. As for the links @Shepmaster has provided, to my point of view this is not an issue of NLL so as I use the latest Rust version.

Comment: *this is not an issue of NLL so as I use the latest Rust version* — this clearly indicates that you did not completely read the links. All of the problems in the links manifest with the current **stable** compiler, Rust 1.48.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`by_name()` returns data that points inside the object that represents the archive. At the same time, it takes a `&mut` reference to the archive, presumably because it needs to update some internal data structures while reading. The unfortunate consequence is that you cannot call `by_name()` while holding on to data returned by a previous call to `by_name()`. In your case the arm of the match that goes on to access the archive *doesn't* contain references into the archive, but the borrow checker is not yet smart enough to detect that.

The usual workaround is to do it in two steps: first, determine whether the manifest file is present, and then either retrieve it by name or search for it among `file_names()`. In the latter case you will need to do another split, this time by cloning the name of the file before calling `by_name()` again. This is for the same reason: `by_name()` requires a mutable reference to the archive which cannot be obtained while you're holding on to the file name that refers to the data inside it. Cloning the name creates a fresh copy at a (usually negligible) run-time cost, allowing the second call to `by_name()`.

Finally, you can combine the `ok_or_else()` combinator with the `?` operator to simplify error propagation. With all these applied, the function could look like this:

```
fn get_manifest_data(apk_path: &Path) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let f = File::open(apk_path)?;
    let mut apk_as_archive = zip::ZipArchive::new(f)?;

    let not_found = matches!(
        apk_as_archive.by_name(MANIFEST_MF_PATH),
        Err(zip::result::ZipError::FileNotFound)
    );
    let _manifest_entry = if not_found {
        let entry_name = apk_as_archive
            .file_names()
            .find(|f| f.eq_ignore_ascii_case(MANIFEST_MF_PATH))
            .ok_or_else(|| zip::result::ZipError::FileNotFound)?
            .to_owned();
        apk_as_archive.by_name(&entry_name).unwrap()
    } else {
        apk_as_archive.by_name(MANIFEST_MF_PATH)?
    };

    Ok(String::new()) //stub
}
```

Comment: The root problem is that that the original code should be safe and accepted as written because the "second" mutable access is only done in case of an `Err` which _doesn't_ have a reference to `apk_as_archive`. That's what the proposed "Polonius" extension to the borrow checker would allow.

Comment: @Shepmaster That's a good point, I've now amended the answer to mention it. Note, though, that the OP's code is a bit more complex than that, because it _also_ calls `by_name()` with the entry name extracted using `file_names()`, which won't be fixed by Polonius. This made it non-trivial to fix the code according to the instructions in previous answers, especially for a beginner. (The question is probably still a duplicate, just not a trivial one.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and working code! Indeed, I am a novice in Rust: this is my first pet project in Rust, so I spend a lot of time to understand what are the errors and what cause them. So as Rust is quite different from the most of the languages, I try to understand how usual things are implemented in it.