# "cannot borrow as mutable more than once" even after dropping the first borrow

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

```rust
trait Output {
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str);
}

struct DummyOutput {}

impl Output for DummyOutput {
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str) {
        // self does not need to be mut in this reproducer,
        // but it would in the real version
        println!("{}", text);
    }
}

enum EncoderOutput<'a, T> {
    Owned(T),
    Borrowed(&'a mut T),
}

impl<'a, T> AsMut<T> for EncoderOutput<'a, T> {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        match self {
            EncoderOutput::Owned(ref mut o) => o,
            EncoderOutput::Borrowed(b) => b,
        }
    }
}

struct Encoder<'a, O: Output> {
    output: EncoderOutput<'a, O>,
}

impl<'a, O: Output> Encoder<'a, O> {
    // here's the idea:
    // every child instance will have a borrowed output,
    // and always only one level of indirection, i.e.:
    // - root: "&mut O" or "O"
    // - child1: "&mut O"
    // - child2: "&mut O"
    // but never:
    // - childN: "&mut &mut O"
    fn child(&'a mut self) -> Self {
        Encoder {
            output: EncoderOutput::Borrowed(self.output.as_mut()),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut enc1 = Encoder {
        output: EncoderOutput::Owned(DummyOutput {}),
    };

    {
        // I know this borrows mutably from enc1
        let mut enc2 = enc1.child();

        // so this will obviously not work:
        // enc1.output.as_mut().write("bar 2b");

        // but this does work:
        enc2.output.as_mut().write("bar 2a");
    } // but then the borrow "enc2" should be dropped here?

    // so why does this fail with:
    // "cannot borrow [...] as mutable more than once"
    enc1.output.as_mut().write("bar 3");
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `enc1.output` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:68:5
   |
57 |         let mut enc2 = enc1.child();
   |                        ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
68 |     enc1.output.as_mut().write("bar 3");
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     first borrow later used here
```

My instinct tells me this fails because the lifetime of the borrow in the `Encoder` returned by `child()` has the same lifetime as the "parent" - but I don't see a way to decouple the lifetimes, even though the returned value should clearly have a smaller-or-equal lifetime than the parent, since it can be dropped beforehand.

I did try a version without the `EncoderOutput` first as well, just having a `&mut O` directly in `Encoder`, but the problem was the same.

My line of thought why this should work: When the scope in `main()` ends, `enc2` is dropped, and the implicit `Drop` impl for it runs, which cleans up the `EncoderOutput::Borrowed` and the reference within, thus leaving no other `&mut` ref to `enc1`, and `enc1` can be mutably borrowed again.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067031/155423); [Moved variable still borrowing after calling `drop`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428894/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```rust
fn child(&'a mut self) -> Encoder<'a, O>;
```

To:

```rust
fn child(&mut self) -> Encoder<'_, O>;
```

Fixed compiling example:

```rust
trait Output {
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str);
}

struct DummyOutput {}

impl Output for DummyOutput {
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str) {
        println!("{}", text);
    }
}

enum EncoderOutput<'a, T> {
    Owned(T),
    Borrowed(&'a mut T),
}

impl<'a, T> AsMut<T> for EncoderOutput<'a, T> {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        match self {
            EncoderOutput::Owned(ref mut o) => o,
            EncoderOutput::Borrowed(b) => b,
        }
    }
}

struct Encoder<'a, O: Output> {
    output: EncoderOutput<'a, O>,
}

impl<'a, O: Output> Encoder<'a, O> {
    // line below changed from:
    // fn child(&'a mut self) -> Encoder<'a, O> {
    // to:
    // child(&mut self) -> Encoder<'_, O> {
    fn child(&mut self) -> Encoder<'_, O> {
        Encoder {
            output: EncoderOutput::Borrowed(self.output.as_mut()),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut enc1 = Encoder {
        output: EncoderOutput::Owned(DummyOutput {}),
    };

    {
        let mut enc2 = enc1.child();
        enc2.output.as_mut().write("bar 2a");
    }

    enc1.output.as_mut().write("bar 3");
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c886b16a58fa3f1b80ec1570037fcffe)

---

**Explanation**

`&'a self` and `&'a mut self` are the most common lifetime traps in all of Rust that most beginners and even intermediate-level Rustaceans eventually fall into. I knew that line in your example was wrong the second I saw it, without even trying to understand anything else about the rest of your code. Over 99.9% of the time `&'a self` and `&'a mut self` are wrong and it should raise a big red flag whenever you see either, and when you do see them you should aggressively refactor them. Okay, so with that out of the way, here's why they are so bad:

If you have some container which contains a reference, let's call it `Container<'a>`, then what is the lifetime of the container? It's the same lifetime as its reference, as the container cannot outlive what it is containing. Let's call that lifetime `'a`. Very important: the `'a` in `Container<'a>` represents *the entire lifetime of the container*. So when you write a method with a `&'a self` or `&'a mut self` receiver what you are communicating to the compiler is *"In order to call this method, the method must borrow the container for the remainder of its entire lifetime."* Now when is this something that you actually want? Virtually never! It's extremely rare that you need to write a method that can only ever be called exactly once because it permanently borrows `self` for the rest of `self`'s lifetime. Ergo, `&'a self` and `&'a mut self` are newbie traps, avoid them.

**Clarification**

`&'a self` and `&'a mut self` are only red flags when `'a` represents the entire lifetime of `self` itself. In scenarios like below, where the `'a` is scoped just to a single method, then it's fine:

```rust
// 'a only local to this method, this is okay
fn method<'a>(&'a self) {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: I feel like this sends the wrong message, annotating the lifetime of `&self` is sometimes required if other lifetimes can't be inferred. The `&'a self` construction in isolation isn't the red flag (its used extensively for methods on [str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) for example). Its the `&'a SomeType<'a>` construction that is almost definitely wrong, where the reference's lifetime is bound to the container's generic lifetime.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for your comment. I've added a clarification to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The code I posted obviously was just an excerpt, but your insight helped me figure out the original issue too. There I was additionally dealing with a boxed future, so while I had to constrain `&mut self` with a lifetime, I got it to work by explicitly specifying one that isn't related to `self`s lifetime. E.g.: `impl<'a> X<'a> { fn recursive<'a, 'b>(&'b mut self, encoder: &'b mut Encoder<'a>) -> BoxFuture<'b, ()> { ... } }` - if it helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

After some messing about, the solution is to change `child` to:

```rust
    fn child(&mut self) -> Encoder<'_, O> {
        Encoder {
            output: EncoderOutput::Borrowed(self.output.as_mut()),
        }
    }
```

Now I knew that the issue was with one method having lifetimes such that rustc inferred the subject (self) had to remain borrowed for both no longer than and longer than it lives, and so once the method was called you'd be "locked out" of it. Sadly I can't remember the precise issue or find a previous instance of it, though I know they exist.

So while I can think of possible explanations, because I've no idea if they're any correct I'm not going to provide any, sorry. But basically by using `'_` you're telling rustc to give you a new output lifetime and figure out the bounds.