# Borrow checker error when overwriting variable with mutable reference

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct `UI` holding a mutable reference to `Stdout`. Instead of mutating it on update, I'd prefer to replace it with an entirely new `UI`:

```rust
use std::io::{stdout, Result, Stdout, Write};

struct UI<'s> {
    stdout: &'s mut Stdout,
    v: Box<()>, // If remove this field, the error goes away.
}

impl<'s> UI<'s> {
    fn new(stdout: &'s mut Stdout) -> Result<Self> {
        let ui = UI {
            stdout: stdout,
            v: Box::new(()),
        };

        Ok(ui)
    }

    fn write(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        write!(self.stdout, "heyyyyy")?;
        self.stdout.flush()?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut stdout = stdout();
    let mut ui = UI::new(&mut stdout)?;

    ui = UI::new(&mut stdout)?;
    ui.write()?; // If you comment this line out, the error goes away.

    Ok(())
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3153a5476ef33e80bf96b35d31ddf8b4)

The borrow checker complains that stdout is borrowed mutably twice:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `stdout` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:30:18
   |
28 |     let mut ui = UI::new(&mut stdout)?;
   |                          ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
29 | 
30 |     ui = UI::new(&mut stdout)?;
   |     --           ^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     |
   |     first borrow might be used here, when `ui` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `UI<'_>`
```

There are two weird behaviors:

1. If I remove field `v`, the error goes away.
2. If I remove `ui.display()?`, the error also goes away.

What's the problem here?

Addressing [@kmdreko's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko):

> The first point is explained in the error message, albeit in a roundabout way if you don't know what's going on. `Box` implements `Drop`, so that it can deallocate its contents when destroyed; and therefore `UI` automatically implements `Drop`, which means there is code executed which could access `stdout` between reborrowing it for a new `UI` and assigning it to `ui`.

Then why does this return an error?

```rust
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut stdout = stdout();
    let mut ui = UI::new(&mut stdout)?;

    for _ in 0..10 {
        drop(ui);

        ui = UI::new(&mut stdout)?;
        ui.write()?;
    }
    
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `stdout` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:33:22
   |
28 |     let mut ui = UI::new(&mut stdout)?;
   |                          ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
33 |         ui = UI::new(&mut stdout)?;
   |         --           ^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |         |
   |         first borrow might be used here, when `ui` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `UI<'_>`
```

[Someone on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/myidbf/how_to_replace_a_struct_which_keeps_a_mutable/gvvz0vi?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) suggested to implement `take(self) -> &'s mut Stdout` for `UI` and it works, but I have no idea why. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=51d03343f94702dc9ef3d79a47b92e9c).

Comment: The first point *is* explained in the error message, albeit in a roundabout way if you don't know what's going on. `Box` implements `Drop`, so that it can deallocate its contents when destroyed; and therefore `UI` automatically implements `Drop`, which means there is code executed which *could* access `stdout` between reborrowing it for a new `UI` and assigning it to `ui`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the second though, it could be the compiler realizes that `ui` isn't used and therefore doesn't *actually* do the assignment, but that's just a guess.

Comment: `take()` is a nice solution IMHO, but note that a more idiomatic name for the method would be `into_stdout()` - in Rust the `into_<something>` methods consume `self` and return the ownership of the thing inside that the object used to own. In this case you get back the original `&mut stdout` (with the original lifetime), which allows you to create a new `ui` that is "compatible" with the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When replacing a value, the new value must be created first:

```
struct Noisy(u8);

impl Noisy {
    fn new(v: u8) -> Self {
        eprintln!("creating {}", v);
        Self(v)
    }
}

impl Drop for Noisy {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        eprintln!("dropping {}", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut ui = Noisy::new(1);
    ui = Noisy::new(2);
}
```

```
creating 1
creating 2
dropping 1
dropping 2
```

This means that your two `UI` structs would attempt to coexist. Since they both have a mutable reference to `stdout`, the `Drop::drop` implementation *might* mutate `stdout`, which would violate the rules of references as there would be multiple active mutable references at one point.

When you don't call `write`, the non-lexical borrow checker sees that the borrow isn't needed, so there's no problem.

> Then why does [explicitly dropping the value before reassigning it] return an error?

Because that is [a limitation of the current borrow checker implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70919).

See also:

- [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423)
- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/155423)
- [Does Rust free up the memory of overwritten variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48227347/155423)
- [Moved variable still borrowing after calling `drop`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428894/155423)
- [What are the options to end a mutable borrow in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35765440/155423)